# iText / Cloud Print not working on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, itext, google-cloud-print

I'm trying to generate a simple PDF and have it passed over to Google Cloud Print, but nothing happens when I try printing the PDF to my google drive. (Login works)
How would I even authenticate that my PDF is whole and valid, for starters? I feel like I'm taking iText's word for it.

Also, I get some error telling me that

```
public class PDFViewer extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode
                  (WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    InputStream object = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.itextkey);
    LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(object);

    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
               .getAbsolutePath() + java.io.File.separator + "HelloWorld.pdf");
    boolean externalStorageAvailable = false;
    boolean externalStorageWriteable = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    // if we can read and write to storage
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        externalStorageAvailable = true;
        externalStorageWriteable = true;
    }
    // else if we can read but cannot write
    else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        externalStorageAvailable = true;
        externalStorageWriteable = false;
        } 
    if (externalStorageWriteable) {
        System.out.println("enough storage!");
        // creation of a document-object
        Document document = new Document();
        try {
            // we create a writer that listens to the document
            // and directs a PDF-stream to a file
        if (f.exists())
           f.delete();
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
         PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream
             (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
             .getAbsolutePath() + java.io.File.separator + "HelloWorld.pdf"));
     // open + format the document
       document.open();
           document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
      } catch (DocumentException de) {
          System.err.println(de.getMessage());
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
          System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
      }
       document.close();
   }
   Intent printIntent = new Intent(this, PrintDialogActivity.class);
   Uri hello = Uri.fromFile(f);
   printIntent.setDataAndType(hello, "application / pdf");
   printIntent.putExtra("title", "stuff");
   startActivity(printIntent);
```

I get this error which I have 0 idea what to do about:

```
04-29 03:41:18.502: E/chromium(749): external/chromium/net/disk_cache
                  /backend_impl.cc:1107: [0429/034118:ERROR:backend_impl.cc(1107)]
                  Critical error found -8
```

I'd like to know what I can try to play with to get this working. The PrintDialogActivity is stock from Google's website , by the way. I turned off Exchange in App settings, I've allowed external storage to be written to in the manifest, and internet has also been enabled.

Thanks

Comment: Easiest and fastest way to check if iText is working is to check the PDF on your external storage. If it is corrupt, the reader will tell you. If you can't see "Hello World" in the PDF, please provide exceptions.

Comment: I used the DDMS to check up on it and nothing shows up in the "sdcard" folder. Any ideas?

Comment: does your logcat show any error, exception, message, anything?

Comment: correction: the file is there. I can see it now with the adb shell. For some reason DDMS wasn't showing it. So now the question becomes, why is it when I click "print" (to google drive) , I see nothing in my actual google drive? Also, nothing happens after i press "print".

Comment: I'm not versed in Google Drive on Android, can't help you there. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem until I found the solution on the Android developer website: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html.

The `targetSdkVersion` in your app's AndroidManifest.xml is probably set to 17 or higher. In that case, you need to make a small change to the `PrintDialogActivity` that you got from the Google Developer website.  You need to add the annotation, `@JavascriptInterface` to the public methods in the `PrintDialogJavaScriptInterface` class.

```
final class PrintDialogJavaScriptInterface
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getType()
    {
        return cloudPrintIntent.getType();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return cloudPrintIntent.getExtras().getString("title");
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getContent()
    {
        try
        {
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            InputStream is = contentResolver.openInputStream(cloudPrintIntent.getData());
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int n = is.read(buffer);
            while (n >= 0)
            {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, n);
                n = is.read(buffer);
            }
            is.close();
            baos.flush();

            return Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getEncoding()
    {
        return CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onPostMessage(String message)
    {
        if (message.startsWith(CLOSE_POST_MESSAGE_NAME))
        {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```